# Getting import module issue in angular-signature-pad plugin

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I installed **angular-signature-pad** with npm like this:

```
npm i angular-signature-pad
```

I use it in **app.module.ts** like this:

```
import { AngularSignaturePadModule } from 'angular-signature-pad';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ AngularSignaturePadModule.forRoot() ] 
})

export class AppModule { }
```

> ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts: error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular-signature-pad'.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the `--save`:

```
npm install angular-signature-pad --save
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that NPM has some issues regarding module exports. you can try https://github.com/wulfsolter/angular2-signaturepad