# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@ng-plus/signature-pad'

Tags: angular, angular6, signaturepad

I am working on an angular6 project tried to add a signature pad but after [installing the package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-plus/signature-pad) `npm install @ng-plus/signature-pad --save` the error message is showing

[image]

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@ng-plus/signature-pad' in '..\src\app'
```

[image]
Please help me to solve the issue or suggest a signature pad which one working for the angular6 project.

Comment: seems this question has been raised by a few here, and there's no accepted answer yet. as suggested by here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53833549/5538819 you can try `angular2-signaturepad` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a version problem. Try using 0.0.5

Comment: Tried but not working